# How do I find out who is logged into Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

How do I find out which users are logged into a Windows XP machine?

I'm looking for something like the Unix `who` command, or a screen that just gives me a list of users currently logged in.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see logged on users in the `Users` tab in `Task Manager`.

Comment: Windows XP Pro Version 2002 SP3 - there is no Users tab, only Applications, Processes, Performance and Networking.

Answer (score 21):

`qwinsta` from the command line should show you who logged on, though I'm not sure if that's just for terminal server sessions or not.

```
C:\Users\wumpus-home>qwinsta
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           Jeff                      1  Active
```

Comment: Works with rdesktop connections.

Comment: Works "locally" on my Windows 8.0 Enterprise install.

Answer (score 6):

psloggedon - a small utility that is part of the SysInternals Suite of tools

Stand-alone link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In a Batch on windows 7 you could use:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2,* delims= " %%I IN ('qwinsta console') DO echo %%J
```